# Why am I getting a blank screen while following React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I am following the current tutorial:
[Youtube tutorial at 12:51 mins.](https://youtu.be/93p3LxR9xfM?t=771)

I expect to see bunch of posts on my screen but my screen remains blank.
It appears I have followed everything told in the tutorial.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Posts extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.posts')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({posts: data}))
    }

    render() { 
        const postItems = this.state.posts.map(post => (
            <div key={post.id}>
                <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                <p>{post.body}</p>
            </div>
        ));
        return ( 
            <div>
                <h1>Posts</h1>
                { postItems }
            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default Posts;
```

and

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Posts from './components/Posts'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Posts />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My browser screen remains blank and I do not see any errors on console.
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about the tutorial but it looks outdated...

Here is your App.js (parent component):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Posts from './Posts';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { posts: [] };

  //fetch the posts and store them in the state
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => this.setState({ posts }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* pass the state (posts) as props to Posts */}
        <Posts posts={this.state.posts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is your Posts.js:

```
import React from 'react';

// No need for a class based comp
// destructure the props and you have all your data 
const Posts = ({ posts }) => (
  <div>
    {posts.map(post => (
      <div key={post.id}>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
        <hr />
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default Posts;
```

**Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ctszdue9/7/**

Comment: Sorry my bad.. I want the fetch in Posts's not in App. How would I modify code for that?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper In general, in React state should be 'lifted up' - meaning state should reside in the parent component and be passed down to the children... You'll code yourself into a corner eventually if you do not follow this pattern... Having said that you could simply do all of the state initialization, setting and fetching in Posts.js - in other words just get rid of App and do what App is doing in Posts (minus passing the props and simply mapping over it's own state... like so: https://jsfiddle.net/1vd70bzc/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting side effect/ api call inside

```
componentDidMount() { }
```

Change URL

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.posts/
```

TO

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
```

Comment: check your URL OF API